# Error when trying to import data with Marak/faker.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, faker

I can't seem to find my problem. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?
This project is made with Meteor and React.

My import file:

```html
import _ from 'lodash';
import { lorem, faker } from 'faker';
import { Comments } from '../../api/comments/comments';
import { insertComment } from '../../api/comments/methods.js';
import { Bert } from 'meteor/themeteorchef:bert';


Meteor.startup(() => {
 // Great place to generate some data

 // Check to see if data excists in the collection
 // See if the collection has any records
 const numberRecords = Comments.find({}).count();
 if (!numberRecords) {
  // Generate some data...
  _.times(100, () => {
   const title = faker.lorem.title();
   const content = faker.lorem.title();

   insertComment.call({
    title, content,
   }, (error) => {
    if (error) {
           Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger');
       } else {
           target.value = '';
           Bert.alert('Comment added!', 'success');
       }
   });
  });
 }
});
```

And this is the method file I use to write the comment:

```html
import { Comments } from './comments';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';
import { rateLimit } from '../../modules/rate-limit.js';

export const insertComment = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'comments.insert',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    title: { type: String },
    content: { type: String },
  }).validator(),
  run(comment) {
    Comments.insert(comment);
  },
});

rateLimit({
  methods: [
    insertComment,

  ],
  limit: 5,
  timeRange: 1000,
});
```

This is the error code I am getting in my terminal:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lorem' of undefined.

Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT:

As suggested I made the changes to the import from "import { lorem, faker } from 'faker';" to "import faker from 'faker';"

I also changed this "faker.lorem.title();" to "faker.hacker.noun();"

Thanks Guig!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It looks like](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/master/lib/index.js) Faker is exporting `faker` as a default, and not as a constant. So you should do

```
import faker from 'faker';
// then use `faker.lorem` as you are currently doing
```

or

```
import { lorem } from 'faker';
// then use `lorem` instead of `faker.lorem`
```

Currently, you are doing

```
import { lorem, faker } from 'faker';
```

and then using `faker.lorem`, so the `lorem` you're importing is not used. And the `faker` you are trying to import is undefined, so calling `faker.lorem(...` throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lorem' of undefined.` as excepted.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clear explanation and taking the time to write your answer! Gonna try it out.

Comment: Ok great, I am one step close. I made the changes you said. So am only using:
--> import faker from 'faker';
And I changed the "faker.lorem.title" to "faker.hacker.noun();" which seems to work. But now I am getting a new error which has to do with the insert method:

Exception in delivering result of invoking 'comments.insert': ReferenceError: target is not defined

Comment: Eventhough I still get an error, it does work and import the data from faker! Thanks again!

Comment: Well that's something else. From the code you've pasted, you're doing `target.value = '';` while `target` is defined nowhere. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but not surprised it fails